# Libkmod Error appearing when Ubuntu 14.04 starts

Tags: startup

```
libkmod: error ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 
kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf 
line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'sudo'
```

Today after I ran a software update I had to restart the computer and this message appeared before Ubuntu 14.04 starts.

I have an BENQ Joybook A33E.

What I should do to fix this error?

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved.
I removed the file `iwlwifi.conf` with the command line:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

After restart, Ubuntu notified me that it had found a "critical error". I clicked <kbd>Send Report</kbd> and after 4 days an automatic update proceeded and everything works fine now.